# Error compiling HDF5 with MinGW and CMake

Tags: c, windows, mingw, hdf5

I'm trying to compile HDF5 with MinGW's gcc 4.8.1 and CMake. I followed the instructions in the `INSTALL_CMake` documentation for Windows and read everything that I found on Google but I still get the following errors:

```
In file included from c:\mingw32-xy\include\fcntl.h:37:0,
                 from C:\Users\jicervan.NDC\Downloads\hdf5-1.8.13\hdf5-1.8.13\src\H5private.h:53,
                 from C:\Users\jicervan.NDC\Downloads\hdf5-1.8.13\hdf5-1.8.13\src\H5detect.c:57:
c:\mingw32-xy\include\io.h:301:1: error: unknown type name 'off64_t'
 __CRT_INLINE off64_t lseek64 (int, off64_t, int);
 ^
c:\mingw32-xy\include\io.h:301:36: error: unknown type name 'off64_t'
 __CRT_INLINE off64_t lseek64 (int, off64_t, int);
                                    ^
c:\mingw32-xy\include\io.h:302:1: error: unknown type name 'off64_t'
 __CRT_INLINE off64_t lseek64 (int fd, off64_t offset, int whence) {
 ^
c:\mingw32-xy\include\io.h:302:39: error: unknown type name 'off64_t'
 __CRT_INLINE off64_t lseek64 (int fd, off64_t offset, int whence) {
                                       ^
In file included from C:\Users\jicervan.NDC\Downloads\hdf5-1.8.13\hdf5-1.8.13\src\H5private.h:70:0,
                 from C:\Users\jicervan.NDC\Downloads\hdf5-1.8.13\hdf5-1.8.13\src\H5detect.c:57:
c:\mingw32-xy\include\unistd.h:65:20: error: unknown type name 'off_t'
 int ftruncate(int, off_t);
```

The errors and warnings go on and on with a long list of warnings and undefines. Does anybody has any suggestions on how to solve this problem? Are there any other alternatives like using the Visual Studio binaries with MinGW maybe?

Comment: Those are POSIX typedefs. You probably need the `unistd.h` header, I think there are POSIX-compliant headers and C libraries available for MinGW on Windows.

Comment: @EOF You we're in the right track, it turned out to be a problem with `io.h` and `unistd.h`. The issue was reported to the MinGW32 folks a while back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got it working. My first attempt was to use `configure` and `make` according to the documentation in the `/release_docs/INSTALL_MinGW.txt` file, but it didn't work. I ended up using CMake. For documentation purposes, here's the procedure that I followed:

`OPERATING SYSTEM: Windows 8.1 pro`

`COMPILER: CMake + MinGW gcc version 4.8.1`

`HDF5 VERSION: 1.8.13`

**STEPS:**

1. Uncompress the `hdf5-1.8.13.zip` file.
2. Download CMake, and run the GUI.
3. Set the source folder to `<hdf5-location>/hdf5-1.8.13` and the build folder to the folder where you want to place your Makefile.

[image: CMake GUI]

4. Click on `Configure`, and a pop-up window will appear. Choose the `MinGW Makefiles` option as the generator for your project, and select the `Use default native compilers option`.

[image: Project Generator]

5. Once the list is populated with options, leave the default checkboxes selected, and also select `BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARIES`. Now the fun begins; compiling.

[image: Options]

6. Locate the file `H5pubconfig.h` file in your HDF5 build folder and append the following lines:

   ```
   // Define Windows 32
   #ifndef H5_HAVE_WIN32_API
   #ifdef WIN32 /* defined for all windows systems */
   #define H5_HAVE_WIN32_API 1
   #endif
   #endif

   // Define MinGW
   #ifndef H5_HAVE_MINGW
   #ifdef __MINGW32__ /*defined for all MinGW compilers */
   #define H5_HAVE_MINGW 1
   #endif
   #endif

   // Redefine _In_ and _Out_ to empty values
   #define _In_
   #define _Out_

   // Redefine off_t and off64_t to match io.h and unistd.h
   #define off_t _off_t
   #define off64_t _off64_t
   ```
7. On the file `io.h`located in `<MyFolder>/MinGW32/include/` change every instance of `off64_t` to `_off64_t`.
8. On the file `unistd.h`located in `<MyFolder>/MinGW32/include/` change every instance of `off_t` to `_off_t`.
9. On the MinGW/MSYS command prompt, change directory to the location of your HDF5 Makefile (set on step 3).
10. Type the command `Make` and verify that it's compiled correctly.
11. Don't forget to include the flags `-I/<your-HDF5-build-folder>/include/`, `-L/<your-HDF5-build-folder>/bin/`, and `-lhdf5` when you compile. Happy coding.